# How do I get navigator.registerProtocolHandler() to work

Tags: javascript, protocols

I want to write a web application that opens a link in a custom protocol, like `myprotocol:someinformationgoeshere`. You know, sort of like mailto:. For example, if people had in their HTML a link of the kind: `<a href="myprotocol:someinformationgoeshere">link</a>` it would open the link through my web application.

However, I can't seem to make this work. The only thing I have found is registerProtocolHandler() and that doesn't seem to work due to security concern.

Comment: Security concern? I can't see where this could go wrong.